# Inserting Data into MONGODB with POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using npm request to insert data into MongoDB - like a direct injection using the variables of a form. This is what I can see in the browser after I click the submit button:
[FORM DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOo7j.png)

And this is the script I'm using to insert credentials into the DB:

```
request.post(
            'http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post', {
                json: {
                    fname: 'john',
                surname:'smtith',
                age:100,
                password: '123as',
                email: 'email@email.com',
                phone: 9283746,
                city: 'anywhere',
                country: 'AZSW',
                postal_code: 117058,
                picture: 'something.jpg',
                description:'description'
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body)
                }
            }
        );
```

This the server side function:

```
app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    var response = {fname: req.body.fname, surname: req.body.surname, age: req.body.age, 
password: req.body.password,email: req.body.email, phone: req.body.phone, 
city: req.body.city, country: req.body.country, postal_code: req.body.postal_code, 
description: req.body.description, picture:req.body.picture};

//etc
```

The issue is that the server gets all messed up with the variables and does a random match of the sent data. Also, in the mongo shell I can see that data comes as "undefined"...Is it because I'm sending a Json and the server side is set to capture variables?

EDIT: these are the [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6u54.png) of the server

Comment: "the server gets all messed up with the variables", example? and how are you inserting data to mongo

Comment: Doesn't Mongoose work for you? `new Model.save()` ?

Comment: well, I've tried, but havent managed to make it work, also this package seemed quite more simpler

Comment: @Yogesh_D I've updated the post with the console logs

Comment: Do this: let reqBody = JSON.parse(req.body); and next use reqBody.fname... etc

Comment: @F.bernal, well, actually the code is working...The mess was all about the regexs and multiple console.logs..., so the mess was mine. I've cleaned that up and now it's working. I dont need Json parsing, Node is ready to work with it, but thanks anyway for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

First do the json parse of the request body:

```
let reqBody = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

Next create your data Model, for example, user:

```
newUser = new User({
    'attr1': reqBody.attr1,
    'attr2': reqBody.attr2,
    'attrN': reqBody.attrN
});

newUser.save(function storeUser(err, user) {
   //TODO: check if the user was saved correctly.
});
```

Comment: that is in server side

Comment: well, now I get this error when running the client side: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: More information about you JSON is needed... post your JSON may be it is malformed and where is the error being shown? line of code I mean.